# How to use VBA to log into website on IE with data-automation-id tag?

Tags: excel, vba, authentication, internet-explorer

I have read through so many websites, articles, and forums on this topic, but have not been able to get this to work for me.  I am trying to log into a website using VBA in Excel, but I'm running into issues because the username and password text fields do not have a typical "name" or "id" associated with them.  They instead have a "data-automation-id" which I can't figure out how to incorporate into the VBA code.  My code errors out where the username and password are being entered into the website.  I get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method."  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the HTML code for only the portions that refer to the username and password fields.

```
<input class="form-control__formControl___3uDUX" type="text" value="" data-automation-id="uname">

<input class="form-control__formControl___3uDUX" type="password" value="" data-automation-id="pwd">

<button disabled="" class="app-btn spin-wrapper spin-button spinner" data-automation-id="loginBtn">
```

This is the VBA code to access this site.  NOTE:  The username and password aren't real, and won't actually allow anyone to login even if the code works.

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Const cUsername = "blahblah@gmail.com"
    Const cPassword = "somepassword"
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://retaillink.login.wal-mart.com/"
Do
  DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
HTMLDoc.all.uname.Value = cUsername
HTMLDoc.all.pwd.Value = cPassword

For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName(“input”)
If MyHTML_Element.Type = “submit” Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
Next
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
Err.Clear
Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test the code and found that when you try to set the value to the text boxes, it just shows the blank page while clicking the login button.

It can be possible that some code gets fired from the site when the user inputs the values manually. When we try to automate, it can possible that the code does not get triggered which leads us to a blank page.

I try to make a test by firing different events but it did not work.

As a workaround, you can try to use `Sendkeys()` instead of setting the value.

```
Sub demo()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim allInputs As Object
    Const cUsername = "blahblah@gmail.com"
    Const cPassword = "somepassword"
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://Your_site_address_here.../" 'please modify the URL here...

While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
Set allInputs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each inputx In allInputs

    If inputx.getAttribute("data-automation-id") = "uname" Then
    inputx.Focus
    SendKeys (cUsername)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    End If
    
    If inputx.getAttribute("data-automation-id") = "pwd" Then
    inputx.Focus
    SendKeys (cPassword)
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
    End If
Next inputx

IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, amazing!  The `SendKeys` function was the exact thing that was needed to get the code to work.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Generally it is not good practice to use the Sendkeys(). When no other approaches work then we can use it. Make sure IE browser does not lose focus while Sendkeys() gets executed. Otherwise, values will get enter in the application that has focus.

Comment: Ok got it.  Can you explain why it isn't good to use `SendKeys`?

Comment: As I informed you, Sendkeys() sends the keystrokes to the currently active window.  there can be a possibility that at the time of execution, another app got to focus in any way and keystrokes get sent to that application. Your code will get break in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page only contains two `<input>`, the guess is pretty easy.
First you get all the `input` of the page:

```
Set allInputs = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

The list contains only two elements. Now, you can use the `.getAttribute()` function to check the value and set it accordingly:

```
For Each input In allInputs
    If input.getAttribute("data-automation-id") = "uname" Then input.Value = cUsername
    If input.getAttribute("data-automation-id") = "pwd" Then input.Value = cPassword
Next input
```

Then you get the only `button` present in the page and click it:

```
IE.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).Click
```

Comment: Great, this worked... kinda.  I did not know about the `.getAttribute()`  function. I made one update to your code where the "input" in the For loop, I updated to "inputx" as VBA wouldn't allow me to use "input" as the variable.  I'm assuming because it might already be an existing, defined function in VBA.

Comment: So although the username and password values are inputted into the text field on the website, the "Log In" button does not get activated afterwards, and therefore, it cannot be clicked.  I believe the reason is because the username and password are being passed into the "value" of the input fields which is not the same as the texts actually being entered into the fields.  They simply get added as placeholder values. Hence, is there a value to actually the username and password as inputs into the text fields?

Comment: I got the disabled button to activate by using the following code:  `HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).disabled = False`.  So now the login button is actually clicked after the username and password are inputted into the text fields as values (which I think is the problem), and the page executes, but doesn't actually log into the website.  The page is just blank and when I refresh the page, it simply goes back to the login page.

Comment: It's the same as if I left the username and password blank and clicked on the "Log In" button.  That's how the code executes.

Comment: @SumitShah try to set the value as .innerText instead of .Value

Comment: Thank you for your help Matteo!  Your code helped get me half way there, and Deepak's answer helped with the last half.  The `SendKeys` function did the final trick to input the username and password into the textfields.